# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: Greg]
[image: Eric Kaufman]
[image: Alec]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections when you're out of Beta.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

#### Past moderators

Also, let's thank past pro-tem moderators for their help in guiding this site through beta.

[image: Ivo Flipse]
[image: md5sum]
[image: Greg]
[image: MattChan]

Comment: Good job All!  Keep up the good work!

Comment: Congrats partners in crime!

Comment: Let the havoc begin!

Comment: Thanks @RebeccaChernoff and congrats to @IvoFlipse and @Greg

Comment: Welcome to @MattChan to the Pro-Tem moderator fold! Congratulations! :D

Comment: Welcome, @Alec! It's been a good run, 6.5 years, but it's time for me to move on. You'll do great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay for ourselves!

Now this question is no longer unanswered @Rebecca :D

Comment: And now it even has an upvote and an accepted checkmark! \o/ (:

Answer (score 1):

I want to add that the original moderation team in no way did anything wrong, to the contrary they have served in an exemplary fashion, guiding the site through the original private beta, initial public beta period, and a change in site scope and direction. They have simply gotten to a point in their lives where the Fitness site is not as much of a priority as it once was.

I wish to express deep gratitude and appreciation for the work that they did, and the effort that they expended over the years to make this a wonderful community.

[image: Ivo Flipse]
[image: Nathan Wheeler]
[image: Greg]
[image: MattChan]

Answer (score 1):

Happy to be part of the team, and more than that happy to help build a solid resource for helping folks with their fitness goals.

In my non-keyboard world I work in an ambulance setting and there are so many health problems that result from a lack of fitness. Diabetes, COPD, and a lot of cardiac issues: solid health choices not only let people live longer but that quality of life is *so* much better.

I've been on Fitness SE for over 4 years, and really look forward to another 4 with everyone on here and new people as well.